# Display results from DB array in view laravel

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel

I am having trouble displaying data in the View from arrays in my DB, I have tried multiple methods to no avail. I need to display all of the results in the View from both arrays in the DB `(Name and Url)` - I have tried for loops although I can't seem to target the data correctly. I also do not know where I am going wrong in my code. I am new to Laravel.

Any help would be appreciated.

DB Instance:

```
local.INFO: array (
  '_token' => 'kwsRPOc9YH4pjvmAVsibJULiMUItzZu2BEWimJy6',
  'name' => 
  array (
    0 => 'linkOne',
    1 => 'linkTwo',
  ),
  'url' => 
  array (
    0 => 'urlOne',
    1 => 'urlTwo',
  ),
)
```

Controller:

```
public function addMorePost(TagList $tagslist, Request $request)
{

  Log::info($request);

  foreach($request as $key => $value) {

    TagList::create([
      'name[]'=>[$value],
      'url[]'=>[$value]
    ]);
  }

  $tagslist = \App\Taglist::all();
  return view('addMore', ['tagslist' => $tagslist]);

}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($tagslist as $tag)

  <div>
    <p class="name">{{ $tag->name }}</p>
    <p class="url">{{ $tag->url }}</p>
  </div>

  @endforeach
```

Comment: If both your name field and url field contain arrays, you will need to iterate both of them separately. Why don't you keep one multidimensional array instead of two? That way you can ensure that both arrays will have same number of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is tagged laravel, you can use a collection with combine
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-combine

```
collect($name)->combine($url);
```

will result in

```
linkOne => urlOne,
linkTwo => urlTwo,
```

if you want you could go 1 step further (I see no need) to achieve exactly what is in your view at the moment.

```
$tags = collect($name)->combine($url)->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $tag = new \stdClass();
    $tag->{'name'} = $key;
    $tag->{'url'} = $item;
    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much!